# Unlimited upload files at once in php

Tags: php

I use this **php** code to upload multiple files at once the problem is i can only upload 20 files only i can't upload more than that at once

**php code**

```
<?php
include("../includes/connect.php");
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) !== 'post') header('Location:test.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Beirut');
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$username=$_SESSION['user'];
$parentID = !empty($_GET['parentID']) ? $_GET['parentID'] : 0;;
$parent_id=intval($_GET['parentID']);
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip","PNG","jpeg","bmp","pdf", "doc", "docx","xlsx","xls","txt","csv","pptx","ppt","pptm","dwg","rtf");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "../uploads_images/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach (preg_replace('/ /','-',($_FILES['myfile']['name'])) as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'][$f] == 4) {
           continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'][$f] == 0) {             

            if( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select name from tbl_files where name='$name'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $countfile=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
                if($countfile==0){
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tbl_files(name,parent_id,db_username,db_date,db_isdeleted)VALUES('$name','$parent_id','$username','$date','0')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
                header("location:dms.php?parentID=$parent_id&view");
                }else{header("location:dms.php?parentID=$parent_id&msg=3&view");}
            }

        }
    }
}       
    ?>
```

After googling i found i need to change **upload_max_filesize** i did this i changed to 1G like this **upload_max_filesize=1G** but also the same problem still
that what i change in **php.ini**

**memory_limit=256M**

**post_max_size=1G**

**upload_max_filesize=64M**

I'm using a hosting and domain in **godaddy**

Finally the question is **How i solve my question and can be able to upload Unlimited files at once??!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
max_file_uploads=20
```

to whatever number you want. Such as

```
max_file_uploads=200
```

Don't forgot to restart server.

Comment: you changed `post_max_size=1G` I am saying that change `max_file_uploads=20` to `max_file_uploads=200`. Don't forgot to restart server.

Comment: Then runtime will be the next issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly : yes, it will be, there is only one other way I know which is by using `ini_set`. but for that files need to count first. Is there any other better solution.